# Convert pdfReader to byte[] - Itext Java

Tags: java, spring-boot, itext

I am using itext in Java for updating a pdf file.

- I read the pdf
- I update the content (get PRStream, convert into stream then string, update the string, convert it back PRStream)
- I regenerate the output file using

  ```
  pdfStamper = new PdfStamper(pdfReader, new FileOutputStream("new-file.pdf"));
  ```

It's working all fine, now I want to send the stream as output to a rest API call, how can I convert `pdfReader` to `byte[]`

I have been able to save the file and then read the stream from it using

```
 byte[] stream = Files.readAllBytes(file.toPath());
```

but I don' want to save the file, I want to retrieve the stream directly instead of saving the file and then getting `byte[]` of the newly generated pdf

Comment: Have you tried using a ByteArrayOutputStream instead of a FileOutputStream, and then getting the bytes from the ByteArrayoutputStream?

Comment: Something like: `ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream(); pdfStamper = new PdfStamper(pdfReader, bos); return bos.toByteArray();`

Comment: @Codo For your code proposal to work, there must be a `pdfStamper.close()` before `return bos.toByteArray()`. (The OP also forgot to mention that closing.)

Comment: @Ben or Codo, you may want to make that an actual answer.